# Calling Test Method from another Test Method

Tags: unit-testing

How can I call one test case from another like:

```
[TestMethod]
Public void GetRes()
{
   var Result=ObjectClass.AddMaths(10,20);
   Assert.AreEqual(30, result);
}
```

But I would like to test more then one like the following:

```
public static IEnumerable TestCaseMethod1()
{
    ArrayList ObjList = new ArrayList();
    //How can I write a Test Case For GetRes() & how can I call TestCaseMethod1()
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I think* what you are referring to is data driven testing, which is essentially passing data to a unit test via an attribute on the test method. There are plenty of resources on this topic e.g https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms182527.aspx

I prefer nUnit's methodology for this (as opposed to MSTest which you are using). I'd suggest doing a search for data driven tests with nUnit (http://gigi.nullneuron.net/gigilabs/data-driven-tests-with-nunit/ has a good example).